# How can I browse a complete list of all apps in the Windows 8 store?

Tags: windows-8, windows-store, windows-store-app

The Windows 8 store app lists apps by category ("Spotlight", "Games", "Social", etc.). Is there any way to browse a complete list of apps in the windows 8 store?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do a wildcard search to browse them all in the store, this is kind of a workaround that I just stumbled on while messing around.

**Edit:** It looks like you can use a few different characters, for example:

```
*, # and %
```

[image]

Comment: That's just what I was going to post.

Comment: hahaha beat you to it ;)

Comment: Also, one thing I would like to add. You can use any special character like *, #, %.

Comment: Yup looks like your right, ill add it now.

Comment: Thanks! I see 6125 results, not 7386. Why are our app counts different?

Comment: You are probably in a different region to me, you can change this setting, please mark the answer as correct if it helped you.

Comment: It took me ages to realize that you had to call for the charms (WinKey +c) from within the Store.

Comment: @GuyThomas aren't you an MVP ?

Comment: @TaylorGibb I'am a PowerShell MVP (Not Windows 8!)  The situation reminds me of my old Prof, he was a genius at science, but he could not drive a car.

Comment: @GuyThomas I was not attacking you :) Was just curious cause I have seen your name somewhere, now that you mention it, its probably for PowerShell. Admittedly, the only reason I knew about the search charm was because I use it in a lot of articles at howtogeek :)

Comment: @TaylorGibb No offense taken.